# Rspec Test controller render partial with locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have controller action like

```
def get_status
  status_name = current_user.status
  status_updated_time = current_user.updated_at
  render :partial => 'show_status', :locals => {status_name: status_name, status_updated_time: status_updated_time}
end
```

here I am planning to test local variable values which are passing via render partial. i.e
`status_name`, `status_updated_time`.

Could you please let me know how to write rspecs for render partial with locals in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would move variable logic into a separate method:

```
def get_status
  render partial: 'show_status', locals: get_status_from(current_user)
end

protected

def get_status_from(user)
  { status_name: user.status, status_updated_time: user.updated_at }
end
```

and test that method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that to test the controller, what you're after is a basic feature/integration spec wherein you can simply look for the content held by your partial.

```
feature 'SomeController' do
  background do
    # setup data 
    # and anything else you need for authentication, etc. as your site dictates
  end

  scenario 'viewing the get status page' do
    visit some_controller_get_status_path
    expect(page).to have_text('WHATEVER IS IN THE LOCAL VAR')
  end
end
```

I prefer to use feature specs over controller specs as I seek (but often fail!) to keep my controllers so simple that there is not really much to test in them. With feature specs, I feel like I'm getting more from the test in terms of how my app works, etc.

EDIT: sorry ... hit enter too early :).

For a controller, you could directly test the var value along the lines of:

```
describe "Your Controller", :type => :controller do
  describe "GET get_stuff" do
    it "assigns a value to status_name" do
      get :get_status
      expect(assigns(:status_name)).to eq(['VALUE'])
    end
  end
end
```

That may not be 100% spot-on for a controller spec (again, I don't use them a lot) but I think it should get you on your way should you go controller spec over feature/integration spec.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
it "should render correct partial for get_status" do
  controller.should_receive(:render).with({
    :partial => '_show_status', #here you will have to give the full path like <controller_name>/_show_status
    :locals  => {status_name: <name>, status_update_time: <time>}
  })
  get 'get_status'
end
```